# android - change background for context menu from action bar

Tags: android

I am trying to change the background to light gray for the drop down triggered by the icon placed on the action bar.

Here is my brief AndroidManifest.xml.

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:logo="@drawable/logo" >
```

And here is my styles.xml.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>

<style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dropdown_gray_background</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/dropdown_gray_background</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/dropdown_gray_background</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/dropdown_gray_background</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/dropdown_gray_background</item>
</style>

<style name="SampleStyle" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@drawable/dropdown_gray_background</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/SampleStyle</item>
</style>
```

Here is my menu.xml.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/main_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_menu"
    android:orderInCategory="11111"
    android:title="Menu"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_home"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="Home"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_info"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_doctor_info"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="Info"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/log"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_log"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="Log"/>
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

For now, I am setting the color to the same color to see how it works.

I have no idea why it's not changing the background color for the drop down menu triggered by the button placed on the action bar. It's still dark color.

Can someone point it out?

Thanks.

Comment: <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/overflow_background</item>

Comment: you will have override this in your AppTheme